# DbUnit DbComparisonFailure expected:<uniqueidentifier>

Tags: sql-server, comparison, hana, dbunit

We do databas / dataset comparison.

Source DB: SQL Server
Target DB: SAP HANA

**Error message**:
 
org.dbunit.assertion.DbComparisonFailure: Incompatible data types: (table=dataset, col=JobId) **expected:<uniqueidentifier>** but was:<VARCHAR>

Work-around: `cast(JobId as varchar(36)) JobId`

**But why does this error occure?** JobId is defined as varchar(36) in the source table 
**How to make this work** (The SQLs are generated and manually adding a cast is cumbersome)

Answer (score 2):

Looking through the google results, this seems to be a common issue with MS SQL Servers UniqueIdentifier column type. See http://dbunit.wikidot.com/mssql.

There, they basically put the type mapping in the DBUnit factory code, instead of a CAST on every column:
public class MsSqlDataTypeFactory extends DefaultDataTypeFactory
{
    public static int NVARCHAR = -9;
    public static int UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = -11;

```
public DataType createDataType(int sqlType, String sqlTypeName) throws DataTypeException
{
    if (sqlType == NVARCHAR)
    {
        return DataType.VARCHAR;
    }

    if (sqlType == UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)
    {
        return DataType.VARCHAR;
    }

    return super.createDataType(sqlType, sqlTypeName);
 }
}
```

Comment: Many thx Lars - even pointing out the solution in this case :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lars Br answer:

I made the following solution:

1. Remove DbUnit jar from classpath (version 2.5.4)
2. Add DbUnit source code (also version 2.4.5)
3. Edit the class org.dbunit.ext.mssql.MsSqlDataTypeFactory
   Method `public DataType createDataType(int sqlType, String sqlTypeName) throws DataTypeException`

   ```
   if(sqlType == Types.CHAR)
   {
       if (UniqueIdentifierType.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_TYPE.equals(sqlTypeName))
       {
           return new UniqueIdentifierType();
       }
   }
   ```

   to

   ```
   /* Do not generate UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_TYPE since it would not match varchar on SAP HANA
   if(sqlType == Types.CHAR)
   {
       if (UniqueIdentifierType.UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER_TYPE.equals(sqlTypeName))
       {
           return new UniqueIdentifierType();
       }
   }*/
   ```